# Cannot recover from sleeping tmux during SSH session

Tags: ssh, zsh, tmux, job-control

I've tried searching this on google but have been very unsuccessful so I've resorted to trying to get someone's help with this.

On my local machine I do the following:

```
$ tmux
CTRL+b CTRL+z
$ fg
```

and I get my TMUX session back, this is pretty simple job control stuff. But if I do the same in an ssh session on another machine I'm not getting my prompt back.

```
$ ssh host
$ tmux
CTRL+b CTRL+z
*Tmux disappears but I never get a prompt back to type 'fg'
```

I have both of the machines using zsh with almost identical setups but I can never regain control of the sleeped tmux process on the ssh session. I would be forever grateful if someone could point me in the right direction

EDIT: (CTRL+b CTRL+z) not just (CTRL+z)

Comment: I could not replicate the behaviour. Client is Mac OS and ssh host is Ubuntu server. `CTRL + z` does not do anything. What is your client OS?

Comment: That was my mistake, you need to execute CTRL+b CTRL+z not just CTRL+z

Comment: Could you try `tmux attach` instead of `fg`

Comment: I don't get a prompt back, I don't get the opportunity to type anything. Hence why I have to close the window. After CTRL+b CTRL+z on the ssh session I don't get any prompt back. It just sits and hangs for me.

Comment: What is the client OS and ssh host OS?

Comment: osx and archlinux

Comment: I double checked with `CTRL + b CTRL + z`. `fg` is recovering the sessions. My `tmux` version is 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this answer. Original poster commented here. So, not deleted.

You should be doing `CTRL + b and d` to detach from Tmux session. You can reattach to Tmux session with `tmux attach`.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but that's not the issue I'm having. The issue is when I have a pane and I want to zoom (ctrl+b z) sometimes I accidentally sleep the process. Then I have to exit that screen, re-ssh and, re-attach to the session.